# How to clear up all commas after deleting all the data in CSV in Excel software?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have this raw `item.CSV` file:

```
Name,Price,date
"item1",10,2012-11-21
"item1",10,2012-11-21
"item1",10,2012-11-21
```

I open it in Excel, it looks correct:

[image]

Then I clear all the data except the headers, and saved it:

[image]

Then I see those commas are there.

[image]

I don't want those commas staying there. How can I clear the data in Excel so that the commas are gone as well in the CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of clearing the data, have you tried deleting it?

Highlight those same 3 rows, right click and choose delete. Then save it.